# Mysql 2 cross tables views not with 1=1 Relation into one view

Tags: php, mysql, max, case

I have a mysql table  with four columns `subfield_id, submission_id, field_id, value`

I made two views:

1.

```
SELECT submission_id, 
       MAX( CASE field_id WHEN '1' THEN value ELSE '0' END ) Usernumber,
       MAX( CASE field_id WHEN '2' THEN value ELSE '0' END ) Company, 
       MAX( CASE field_id WHEN '3' THEN value ELSE '0' END ) Zipp, 
FROM table
GROUP BY submission_id
```

Resultant Table Columns: `Submission_id, Usernumber, Company, Zipp`

2.

```
SELECT submission_id, 
       MAX( CASE field_id WHEN '4' THEN value ELSE '0' END ) Usernumber1, 
       MAX( CASE field_id WHEN '5' THEN value ELSE '0' END ) Partnernumber 
FROM table 
GROUP BY submission_id
```

Resultant Table Columns: `Submission_id, Usernumber1, Partnernumber`

`Usernumber` and `Usernumber1` are the same number

How do I make a view with the following columns?

```
Usernumber, Company,  Zipp, Partnernumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write this in a single query:

```
SELECT submission_id, 
       MAX( CASE field_id WHEN '1' THEN value ELSE '0' END ) as Usernumber,
       MAX( CASE field_id WHEN '2' THEN value ELSE '0' END ) as Company, 
       MAX( CASE field_id WHEN '3' THEN value ELSE '0' END ) as Zipp, 
       MAX( CASE field_id WHEN '5' THEN value ELSE '0' END ) as Partnernumber 
FROM table
GROUP BY submission_id;
```

The views are not going to really help you with this query.

EDIT:

Based on your comment:

```
select *
from view1 v1 join
     view2 v2
     using (Usernumber);
```

Comment: This does not work as Partnernumber has always a different submission_id then Company and Zipp